# In Apache config, should it be "UserDir disabled" or "UserDir disable"?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

I'm comparing two Apache config files (`httpd.conf`), one on a CentOS 6.2 VM with Apache 2.2.15 and one on a RedHat 5.8 server with Apache 2.2.3, and I see a strange difference.

```
UserDir disabled                                          |     UserDir disable
# directory, remove the "UserDir disabled" line above, an |     # directory, remove the "UserDir disable" line above, and
```

In one case `UserDir disabled` is used, and in the other `UserDir disable` is used.  Didn't see the difference?  One ends in `d` and the other doesn't—one uses an *adjective* referring to the resultant *state* of `UserDir`, and the other uses a *verb* telling what Apache should *do* to `UserDir`.

Which is right?  Will both work?

***UPDATE***: Given that this appears to be a sysadmin error, and not a change in syntax from one version of Apache to another, or a mistake in RedHat's distribution of apache, I'm thinking this question may be useless to others and I should delete it.  Thoughts?

Comment: If you are not using it, and depending on how Apache is built `mod_userdir` is a loadable module.  You might save yourself a few K of memory per process if you do not load the module in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UserDir disabled` is the correct syntax; documentation on the keyword is [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html#userdir).

`disable` will probably still effectively disable the behavior; unless your users have directories at `~/disable` then there's nothing to map to with that name.

Comment: aha... it's being treated as a filename pattern, so it gives the appearance of being the same as `disabled`.  I'll have to tell the sysadmin for that RedHat box to fix it... or give me access to httpd.conf.